# issues with installation of software packages

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

[image: when i try to install gpsd package i get the following error shown in image, when i open the Pi folder it shows total memory=1.8GB free space=72MB will this create any issue? My memory card is 4GB i don't know why it is showing less memory]

[image: when i tried to **sudo apt-get update** i get the error in image 2.]

when I try to install gpsd package i get the following error shown in image, when i open the Pi folder it shows total memory=1.8GB free space=72MB will this create any issue? My memory card is 4GB i don't know why it is showing less memory.
when i tried to **sudo apt-get update** i get the error in image 2.
**below description added in this edit**

later i came to know that card ran out of memory, so i expanded the partition i could `sudo apt-get update` but i was unable to install **gpsd** packages, then i used a **NEW** SD card i could **install gpsd packages**. Can anyone tell what went wrong? Is it something like a file regarding `sudo apt-get` got corrupted or my **sd** card got screwed up!!!!!
I am new to Raspberry Pi and Linux, explain whats happening? Is this because of Memory or anything else.

Comment: You are out of space. Maybe your filesystem was not expanded to full 4GB. Try using `raspi-config` and there is an option to expand FS.

Comment: @ppumkin yes i expanded the partition, i was able to **sudo apt-get update** but i am still unable to install **gpsd** packages ...i get the same error as in 1st picture in my question.

Comment: @ppumkin have tried with `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps` its not working, is there any other way so that i can fix this fuss up

Comment: @ppumkin i rebooted but the strange thing here is i get 404 error!!!!!

Comment: Try and ping that address form the Pi - jsut the top level, then your computer. Try and go there with a normal browser. See what happens. Looks like the mirror thing is not working for some reason.

Comment: @ppumkin now, this is called working from scratch anyways good idea!!!!!!

Comment: @ppumkin:  i edited the question can you figure it out now..whats goin on...??

Answer (score 2):

*The error **is NOT** that you are not out of space.*  You may also be out of space, but that is not the problem, or at least, not the primary problem.

The explicit error is that you are perhaps not not connected to the internet -- or, since those are 404 errors ("page not found"), it could be that the pages have really changed and the db needs updating, which is why it wants you to run an update.

The second error implies `apt` is already running in another terminal.  It could also be one that prematurely exited, or because of disk corruption ("no space" might also a symptom or a cause of that).  I would try a reboot, then `apt-get update`.

---

It can also happen that some of the repository servers are down.  I just did a long `apt-get update` here (Canada) -- no problems.  However, when I tried `apt-get install libgps20`, which is the first package (a dependency) that failed for you, I get a similar issue:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgps20
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 233 kB of archives.
After this operation, 466 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libgps20 armhf 3.6-4+deb7u1
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.us.leaseweb.net'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gpsd/libgps20_3.6-4+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.us.leaseweb.net'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Since I had just run an update, I tried:

```
apt-get install --fix-missing libgps20
```

And guess what?  It worked.  So try with `--fix-missing`.

Comment: when i retried expanding the partition i was able to `sudo-apt get update` and it has downloaded many packages, but whats the problem is am unable to install the **gpsd** packages..though i updated...

Comment: That's good.  Have a look at what I've added at the bottom (WRT `--fix-missing`).  BTW, if this works, you should still consider how much space is left in your filesystem...but that's another question ;)

Comment: i have tried with `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps` its not working here in [INDIA] is there any other way so that i can fix this fuss up....

Comment: i edited the question can you figure it out now..whats goin on...???

Answer (score -2):

On my raspberry pi i was able to fix it by just turning on wifi as it is trying to reach a web domain